# Why is python removing each line in the given file when replacing one line?

Tags: python, linux, rhel

I have a config file where i want to replace the line starting with `IPADDR=someIP` by the value stored within my variable `ipaddr`

my code:

```
for line in fileinput.input(["/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192"], inplace=True):
    if line.strip().startswith('IPADDR='):
        line ="IPADDR="+ipaddr
        sys.stdout.write(str((line)) + "\n")
```

It does properly set the line i want, but also deletes every other line, but it should only remove blank lines, why isn't it keeping the other existing lines?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is good except that you are not writing the rest of the file that does not start with 'IPADDR', just add that line and all should be good.

```
for line in fileinput.input(["/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192"], inplace=True):
    if line.strip().startswith('IPADDR='):
        line ="IPADDR="+ipaddr
        sys.stdout.write(str((line)) + "\n")
    elif len(line.strip()) > 0: # add this and below line
        sys.stdout.write(line) + "\n")
```

Comment: thank you very much! that solved my issue :-)) @johnIl

Comment: what will happen if `line.strip().startswith('IPADDR=')` and `len(line.strip()) > 0`  both `true` then it will execute upper body. Then how your problem will get solved??@esha

Comment: nope, its either if or elif will be executed, never both

Answer (score 4):

You should to `write line` for all lines:

```
for line in fileinput.input(["/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192"], 
                            inplace=True):
    if line.strip().startswith('IPADDR='):
        line ="IPADDR="+ipaddr
    sys.stdout.write(str((line)) + "\n")  #<-- here, indentation
```

To skip blank lines, an approach may be:

```
    ...
    stripped = line.strip()
    is_not_blank = bool( stripped )
    startswithIPADDR = not is_blank and stripped.startswith('IPADDR=')
    if is_not_blank:
        if startswithIPADDR:
            line ="IPADDR="+ipaddr
        sys.stdout.write(str((line)) + "\n")  #<-- here, indentation
```

Answer (score 0):

finally solved it using:

```
for line in fileinput.input(["/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192"], inplace=True):
    if line.strip().startswith('IPADDR='):
        line ="IPADDR="+ipaddr
        sys.stdout.write(str((line)) + "\n")
    elif len(line.strip()) > 0:
        sys.stdout.write(str((line) + "\n"))
for line in fileinput.input(["/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192"], inplace=True):
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '': continue
        print line
```

thanks a lot to you both!